# python работа с файлами, мультипроцесинг или многопоточность?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Есть код, который меняет расположение файла, параллельно сортирует в зависимости от типа., но делает это очень медленно и не использует хотя бы на половину ресурсы пк. Подскажите как сюда внедрить многопоточность или мультипроцесинг, посмотрел кучу примеров но дойти пока не могу.

```
    for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(mypath):
        for file in files:
            filepath = subdir + os.sep + file
    
            if filepath.endswith(".*"): # тип файла
    
                # cоздание пути
    
                if check_filepath == check_pth:  # проверка существование
                    break
    
                else:  # cоздание папки
    
                    fpath.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    
                    if not os.path.isfile(fpath):  # в случае копии переместить туда-то
                        os.rename(filepath, fpath)
    
                    else:
                        check_pth.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
                        os.rename(filepath, check_pth)
                        break
    
            elif filepath.endswith(".*"): # другой тип файла
                # cоздание пути
    
                if check_filepath == check_pth:  # проверка существование
                    break
    
                else:  # cоздание папки
    
                    fpath.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    
                    if not os.path.isfile(fpath):  # в случае копии переместить туда-то
                        os.rename(filepath, fpath)
    
                    else:
                        check_pth.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
                        os.rename(filepath, check_pth)
                        break
```

Comment: `не использует ресурсы пк` какие ресурсы? А почему у вас одинаковые условия `filepath.endswith(".*")`? Кст, судя по коду у вас там перебор файлов и папок должен заниматься время, папки большой вложенности?

Comment: Спасибо, добавил в вопрос "хотя бы на половину". Типы файлов там разные, код параллельно сортирует. В общем думаю файлов 50000+ будет.

Comment: половина от мощности процессора, до сих пор не перебрал решил тут спросить, гиг и меньше.

Comment: Это же не числодробилка. В задаче сплошной i/o (ввод-вывод) - в таких задачах проц почти ничего не делает. И в таких задачах распараллеливание может ухудшить производительность. ведь все упирается в диск, а не мощность процессора.

Comment: Понял, спасибо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(mypath):
```

Заменяется на такой код в тредах. Каждый каталог новому треду

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool

pool=Pool(4)

def filesort(subdir, dirs, files):
       Вложенный код тут

pool.map(filesort, os.walk(mypath) )
```

Попробуй поэксперементировать с количеством потоков. Но перемещать слишком много файлов одновременно будет медленней.

Comment: а `pool=Pool(4)` отвечает за количество файлов?

Comment: Количество потоков, количество одновременных каталогов в этом примере.

Comment: Спасибо, а на каком этапе нужно 
`pool.close()
 pool.join()`

Comment: Этот вариант map уже сделает join. Close тогда, когда этот пул уже не нужен - программа продолжает выполняться, но паралельных задачек больше нет. Можно не закрывать для большинства программ

Comment: Спасибо, всё получилось.